# Python: Given 2 processes A and B, call a function in A from B

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

Based on: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers I am rewriting one of the example to be split in 2 processes, a client and a server. It is the following code:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import multiprocessing

class ManagerServer(multiprocessing.Process):
def __init__(self):
    multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)

    class MathsClass(object):
        def add(self, x, y):
            return x + y
        def mul(self, x, y):
            return x * y

    class MyManager(BaseManager): 
        pass

    MyManager.register('Maths', MathsClass)
    m = MyManager(address=('', 50000), authkey='abracadabra')
    self.s = m.get_server()

def run(self):
    self.s.serve_forever()

class ManagerClient(multiprocessing.Process):
def __init__(self):
    multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)

    class MyManager(BaseManager): 
        pass

    MyManager.register('Maths')
    self.m = MyManager(address=('', 50000), authkey='abracadabra')


def run(self):
    self.m.connect()
    maths = self.m.Maths()
    print maths.add(4, 3)
    print maths.mul(7, 8)

if __name__ == "__main__":
ms = ManagerServer()
mc = ManagerClient()

ms.start()
mc.start()
```

This code works, and from the client I can call to the functions inside the class MathsClass from the server.

The problem I am having is that I am limited to functions directly defined in MathsClass that are not handling data from anywhere else.

For example, if in ManagerServer I define a function called "addOuter(self,x,y)", and then inside class MathsClass, in its function add I call addOuter(), it cannot see it, and it says it does not exists.

So, my question is, given two processes, A and B, with A having functions defined in the same level as **init**, not inside another class, how can I call these functions in A from B?

Comment: you need to look into message passing ...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should rename the `self` variable in `MathsClass` to something else to avoid collision. To access a function in `ManagerServer` in your example, you would have to call it statically, with an instance of `ManagerServer` passed to it as the first parameter. Good thing we have one already defined as `self`. This should do the trick:

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import multiprocessing

class ManagerServer(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)

        class MathsClass(object):
            def add(innerSelf, x, y):
                return ManagerServer.addOuter(self, x, y)
            def mul(innerSelf, x, y):
                return x * y

    class MyManager(BaseManager): 
        pass

    def addOuter(self, x, y):
        return x + y

    MyManager.register('Maths', MathsClass)
    m = MyManager(address=('', 50000), authkey='abracadabra')
    self.s = m.get_server()

    def run(self):
        self.s.serve_forever()

class ManagerClient(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)

        class MyManager(BaseManager): 
            pass

        MyManager.register('Maths')
        self.m = MyManager(address=('', 50000), authkey='abracadabra')


    def run(self):
        self.m.connect()
        maths = self.m.Maths()
        print maths.add(4, 3)
        print maths.mul(7, 8)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ms = ManagerServer()
    mc = ManagerClient()

ms.start()
mc.start()
```